SED --- in a string, replace word1 by word2 after token 1 --- replace only once
input string : PARAM
Piece of code that did not work.
PARAM="0 \"  0 - ${TEXT0}\" off  1 \"  1 - ${TEXT1}\" off  2 \"  2 - ${TEXT2}\" off  3 \"  3 - ${TEXT3}\" off  4 \"  4 - ${TEXT4}\" off  5 \"  5 - ${TEXT5}\" off  6 \"  6 - ${TEXT6}\" off  7 \"  7 - ${TEXT7}\" off  8 \"  8 - ${TEXT8}\" off  9 \"  9 - ${TEXT9}\" off  10 \" 10 - ${TEXT10}\" off  11 \" 11 - ${TEXT11}\" off  12 \" 12 - ${TEXT12}\" off  13 \" 13 - ${TEXT13}\" off  14 \" 14 - ${TEXT14}\" off  15 \" 15 - ${TEXT15}\" off  16 \" 16 - ${TEXT16}\" off  17 \" 17 - ${TEXT17}\" off  18 \" 18 - ${TEXT18}\" off  19 \" 19 - ${TEXT19}\" off"
CUR_PARAM=${PARAM}

NEW_PARAM=$(echo ${CUR_PARAM} | sed  -e '/3/ s/off/on/')


Got :
" 0 - Exit" on 1 " 1 -  ..............

expected result :
0 " 0 - Exit" off 1 " 1 - RUN_INITIAL_TASK" off 2 " 2 - (N.I.U) FORBID REF LEAP SERVICE" off 3 " 3 - INSTALL MY REF LEAP SERVICE" **on** 4 " 4 - INSTALL SUDOERS" off 5 " 5 - INSTALL SET LOCALE" off 6 " 6 - REMOVE PACKAGE and SET LOCK" off 7 " 7 - INSTALL MY MINI SYS CONFIG" off 8 " 8 - INSTALL JOURNALD CONFIG" off 9 " 9 - INSTALL PAM.D CONFIG" off 10 " 10 - INSTALL MY BASH FUNCTIONS" off 11 " 11 - INSTALL KERNEL HEADERS and COMPILING TOOLS" off 12 " 12 - INSTALL SSH" off 13 " 13 - INSTALL PUTTY" off 14 " 14 - INSTALL BROTHER PRINTER" off 15 " 15 - INSTALL HPLIP PRINTER" off 16 " 16 - CONFIGURE FIREWALLD" off 17 " 17 - INSTALL VIRTUALBOX HOST MODE 1" off 18 " 18 - INSTALL VIRTUALBOX HOST MODE 2" off 19 " 19 - INSTALL VIRTUALBOX VM GUEST" off


Any help is welcome.

Is that example your actual code? It has a significant number of syntax errors in it. You may want to start off with shellcheck and try to clean it up into something runnable.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP did not use http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag instructs.

sed 's/" off 4 " 4 -/" on 4 " 4 -/'

/3/ resolves to the current address which does in fact contain the string 3. s/off/on/ replaces the first occurrence of off with on.

It's really hard to guess what you are trying to ask, but based on the title, I'm guessing
sed 's/\(3.*\)off/\1on/'

A complication is that .* matches the longest possible string. Based on your data, perhaps something like [^-]* would make more sense, which matches as long as the character is not a dash.
The string inside the parentheses is captured into \1 and we then use the captured string in the replacement to, basically, replace the match with itself, only the string immediately after it is changed from off to on.
You might also want to add word boundary anchors around 3 but what exactly will work depends on which sed dialect you are using. Common alternatives include \<3\>, \b3\b, and [[:<:]]3[[:>:]]
Your attempt /3/ s/off/on/' simply says, replace the first occurrence of off with on on any line which matches /3/.
Separately, quote your variables unless you specifically want the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value, and don't use upper case for your private variables.
echo "$PARAM" | sed 's/\(\<3\>.*\)\<off\>\(.*\<4\>\)/\1on\2/'

... to show yet another variation from the comments below (also without needlessly copying $PARAM to a second variable, but still sticking to the problematic upper case).

sed (GNU sed) 4.4

What I search for : In the input string search for 3 ; then search for off then replace by on. The result will look ,like : .....3 " 3 - INSTALL MY REF LEAP SERVICE" on .......

Your proposal return an error : sed: -e expression #1, char 17: Unmatched ( or (

I fixed a typo where one backslash was missing but it's not visible from the edit history because I changed it within the grace edit period, several minutes before you posted your comment (granted, Stack Overflow does not let you know that you should reload in this scenario).

Your comment repeats information from the question, but it doesn't help to decide what strings can legitimately occur between 3 and the end of 3. If [^-]* doesn't work, maybe [^4]* would work if you want to match up to before the next occurrence of 4?

Seems to work after adding the missing ''. I will make a new test in as soon as possible. I am going out.

Sorry it does not work any more. The change is made on the last 'off' at the end of the string. I have try to search between 3 and 4 but it does not work. I tried echo ${CUR_PARAM} | sed  's/\(\<3\>.*\<4\>\)off/\1on/'  and `echo ${CUR_PARAM} | sed  's/(3.*4)off/\1on/'

That's why I told you to change the .* to something else. What you tried would replace the off after 4 if there was one immediately after, but there isn't. To recap, the expression between the first two slashes needs to match text that you want to replace. The question you still haven't answered is how exactly we can restrict the wildcard I used to only match within the entry you actually want to match. There is no simple way in sed to say "until just before 4" but you could say s/\(\<3\>.*\)\<off\>\(.*\<4\>\)/\1on\2/ to require it to be followed by something containing 4.

OK I see the idea. I make a try to search between 3 and 4

I changed my mind and used awk:

PARAM contains the menu definition.
Change 'off' to 'on' after number '3'.

A_DELIM='3'.  
A_SELECT='on'.  
A_DESELECT='off'.  

echo ${PARAM} > /tmp/000_DATA_MENU.CONF
OUTPUT=$( awk  -v tag=$A_DELIM  -v switch_on=$A_SELECT  -v switch_off=$A_DESELECT '
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            if ($i == tag) flag=1
            if ($i == switch_off && flag==1) {
                $i=switch_on
                flag=0
            }
        }
    }
    {print} '  /tmp/000_DATA_MENU.CONF
)

